# How to test lifecycle on destroy in flutter in debug mode?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, flutter, android-lifecycle

I implemented the lifecycle methods in flutter. Like in the description here: https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/flutter-for/android-devs#how-do-i-listen-to-android-activity-lifecycle-events .
But how can I test onDestroy method? When I destroy my app I get only this output: Lost connection to device. I started this app with flutter run in console.